# Simple Math Error in gfortran?

Tags: floating-point, fortran, gfortran

I am a beginner with regards to programming in Fortran.  I am currently using cygwin and the gfortran compiler running on my Windows XP PC.  I'm having difficulty with some simple math - the program I wrote simply won't do the math.  The code is:

```
program convert
real t

t=0
t=8320671.25 - 8000000.00

write(*,*) t
end
```

The program should give me the answer "320671.25" but gives me 320671.00 instead!
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're running into the single precision limit. The result of the subtraction is a `real*4`, and can be safely stored in `t`. The values *used* in the subtraction, however, are outside the `real*4` range. Outside in the range of precision, with the result that the numbers are rounded to fit into a `real*4` before calculating the subtraction.

Try this for example:

```
program convert
real t

t=0
t=8320671.25_8 - 8000000.00_8

write(*,*) t
end
```

The appended `_8` ensures the two numbers are double precision; the result is then converted to real before assigned to `t`, but the calculation is now in double precision, and the `.25` is "saved" in the subtraction.

Comment: Assuming _8 means 8 bytes seems more of a portabiltiy risk than using `double precision` ..

Comment: To be fair, this answer was created before I added the generic [tag:fortran].  While it's less portable (and even if writing for gfortran, being portable is good) this does explain why the problem comes about.  See [M. S. B.'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27746544/3157076) for the portable way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a worked example using High Performance Mark's suggestion.   The type "8" is not a portable way to specify double precision reals.  Most compilers now support the ISO Fortran environment types used in the example.  If you have an older compiler, you can instead use the the `ISO_C_BINDING` and the type `c_double`, which have been available longer.  As Evert did, it's essential to specify the types of the constants.   The calculation is done on the RHS, then the assignment is made to the variable on the LHS.  It's not enough that the variable on the LHS have sufficient precision.

```
program convert

use, intrinsic :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV

real (real64) :: t
t=8320671.25_real64 - 8000000.00_real64
write(*,*) t

end program convert
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it does not matter for the example you gave, if there were a greater disparity in the magnitudes of the operands, replace

```
real t
```

with

```
double precision t
```

Otherwise, the difference would be truncated to the available storage.

For your example, the precision of the constants is too small.  A floating point value given as you have (`8320671.25` and `8000000.00`) is of type `real` which specifies "single precision": that uses a 32 bit floating point value representation which are equivalent to [6 to 7 decimal digits of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).  `Double precision` is (since the 1980s) usually a 64 bit floating point representation, equivalent to [15 to 17 decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  However some implementations *might* choose to implement `double precision` the same as a `real`, though on IEEE-754 compliant machines, it usually is larger.

To make a floating point constant double, write a `D` for the exponent:

```
t = 8320671.25D0 - 8000000.00
```

Note that making subsequent operands `double precision` won't work due to Fortran's expression typing rules:

```
t = 8320671.25 - 8000000.00D0   ! Wrong!  Result is "real"
```

or

```
t = 8320671.25 - 8D6            ! Wrong!  Result is "real"
```

The first example produces the output `320671.250`.  The others produce `320671.000` (if `t` is type `real`) or `320671.00000000000` if `t` is type `double precision`.

Since the 1940s, Fortran has been implemented on diverse architectures.  On some of them (VAX for example), command line compilation options specify what hardware type is used for `real` and for `double precision`.  DEC's architecture had at least four flavors of floating point (F-Float, D-Float, G-Float, and H-Float), all of which were designed long before IEEE-754.  See [this](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/754story.html) for some historical perspective of the development of IEEE-754.

Comment: No, don't use `double precision`.  It was never guaranteed by the standard to provide 64-bit reals, though most current compilers do implement it as such.  Far better to use either explicit `kind`s or to use associate the standard parameters, such as `real64`, defined in the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env`.

Comment: a bit harsh to downvote considering the example doesn't absolutely need to be 64 bit.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark:  True.  The Cyber implementation used 60 bits for `real` and `double precision`.  The type used to avoid the truncation does not need to be guaranteed to be any particular size, just bigger than it is to avoid what is obviously 32-bit float.

Comment: I down voted this answer 'cos it makes an erroneous statement about the definition of `double precision`.  Had wallyk made a statement such as *double precision provides more precision than a default real, and is probably large enough for your needs* I'd still have disagreed with its use, but wouldn't have down voted for the error.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark:  Okay, now I have taken the time to balance it.  Comments?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark bit harsh - the other answers all implicitly assume precision or range not guaranteed by the standard (e.g real64 from iso_fortran_env designates storage size, not numerical properties) - are you going to down vote them too?  At least the standard has some guarantees for DOUBLE PRECISION, though it isn't what this answer presumes.

Comment: On further look, this answer doesn't address the issue at hand anyway.  You can type declare `t` however you want and It wont fix the literals being 32 bit (probably..). The precision is gone before `t` ever sees it.

Comment: @agentp:  I have corrected it.  I don't recall ever encountering Fortran's expression type promotion rules before, at least not like this.

Comment: @wallyk Leaving aside the confusion mentioned by @IanH (conflation of storage and precision) and implementation details, I'll note that to be Fortran the `double precision` real _must_ have greater precision than the `real` real, so the two cannot be implemented the same.  [Again, this says nothing about storage, but that's not relevant here.]

Comment: I'll also say that I don't follow the "Note that making subsequent operands ..." parts.  [Oh, perhaps I do: you mean "8320671.25 promoted to `double precision` is not the same as 8320671.25D0?]

Comment: @francescalus:  No.  I mean that  `<dbl> + <single>` is a double precision result and `<single> + <dbl>` has a single precision result!  AFAIK, no other high level language does that.  They all promote the result to the greater of the operands.

Comment: @wallyk Fortran doesn't do that either!  The overall kind of a mixed kind real binary operation is the kind with the greatest decimal exponent range, regardless of order.

Comment: @IanH:  I just tried it myself with `gfortran`.  That is what it does.

Comment: @wallyk Are you sure about that?  See F2008 7.1.9.3: "In the case where both operands are any of type real or complex with different kind type parameters, the kind type parameter of the expression is that of the operand with the greater decimal precision if the decimal precisions are different"  [As IanH says.]

Comment: `PRINT"(I0,1X,I0)",KIND(1.0+1.0D0),KIND(1.0D0+1.0);END` with gfortran 4.9.2 outputs `8 8`